# Error while deploying model using Sagemaker endpoint or transformer, which was trained using script mode

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained a model using sagemaker SDK using script mode. When I am deploying it I am getting this error.

[image]

Also, I have tried with the transformer, getting the same error.

It's working fine when I am training using the container.

Need help on this...